# Generate random numbers replicating arbitrary distribution

Tags: python, numpy, random

I have data wherein I have a variable `z` that contains around 4000 values **(from 0.0 to 1.0)** for which the histogram looks like this.

[image]

Now I need to generate a random variable, call it `random_z` which should replicate the above distribution.

What I have tried so far is to generate a normal distribution centered at 1.0 so that I can remove all those above 1.0 to get a distribution that will be similar. I have been using `numpy.random.normal` but the problem is that I cannot set the range from 0.0 to 1.0, because usually normal distribution has a mean = 0.0 and std dev = 1.0.

Is there another way to go about generating this distribution in Python?

Comment: How closely does it have to follow the distribution? Can you use a first-order approximation, rising linearly from z=0..0.5 then flat from z=0.5..1.0 ?

Comment: well it does not need to follow this distribution exactly, it only needs to be somewhat similar. I assume since there seems to be a flattening from 0.5 to 1.0 you are asking this question. Well it can be so. but my idea was to take one half of a normal distribution so that it almost replicates the above

Comment: ... which would be a triangular distribution on the LHS, and a uniform distribution on the RHS?

Comment: There must be 99 different ways to model it, the thing you need to tell us is how much accuracy do you need?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to bootstrap you could use `random.choice()` on your observed series.

Here I'll assume you'd like to smooth a bit more than that and you aren't concerned with generating new extreme values.

Use `pandas.Series.quantile()` and a uniform [0,1] random number generator, as follows.

Training

- Put your random sample into a pandas Series, call this series `S`

Production

1. Generate a random number `u` between 0.0 and 1.0 the usual way, e.g.,
   `random.random()`
2. return `S.quantile(u)`

If you'd rather use `numpy` than `pandas`, from a quick reading it looks like you can substitute [`numpy.percentile()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html) in step 2.

Principle of Operation:

From the sample S, `pandas.series.quantile()` or `numpy.percentile()` is used to calculate the inverse cumulative distribution function for the method of [Inverse transform sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling). The quantile or percentile function (relative to S) transforms a uniform [0,1] pseudo random number to a pseudo random number having the range and distribution of the sample S.

## Simple Sample Code

If you need to minimize coding and don't want to write and use functions that only returns a single realization, then it seems `numpy.percentile` bests `pandas.Series.quantile`.

Let S be a pre-existing sample.

u will be the new uniform random numbers

newR will be the new randoms drawn from a S-like distribution.

```
>>> import numpy as np
```

I need a sample of the kind of random numbers to be duplicated to put in `S`.

For the purposes of creating an example, I am going to raise some uniform [0,1] random numbers to the third power and call that the sample `S`.  By choosing to generate the example sample in this way, I will know in advance -- from the mean being equal to the definite integral of (x^3)(dx) evaluated from 0 to 1 -- that the mean of S should be `1/(3+1)` = `1/4` = `0.25`

In your application, you would need to do something else instead, perhaps read a file, to
create a numpy array `S` containing the data sample whose distribution is to be duplicated.

```
>>> S = pow(np.random.random(1000),3)  # S will be 1000 samples of a power distribution
```

Here I will check that the mean of S is 0.25 as stated above.

```
>>> S.mean()
0.25296623781420458 # OK
```

get the min and max just to show how np.percentile works

```
>>> S.min()
6.1091277680105382e-10
>>> S.max()
0.99608676594692624
```

The numpy.percentile function maps 0-100 to the range of S.

```
>>> np.percentile(S,0)  # this should match the min of S
6.1091277680105382e-10 # and it does

>>> np.percentile(S,100) # this should match the max of S
0.99608676594692624 # and it does

>>> np.percentile(S,[0,100])  # this should send back an array with both min, max
[6.1091277680105382e-10, 0.99608676594692624]  # and it does

>>> np.percentile(S,np.array([0,100])) # but this doesn't.... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 2803, in percentile
    if q == 0:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

This isn't so great if we generate 100 new values, starting with uniforms:

```
>>> u = np.random.random(100)
```

because it will error out, and the scale of u is 0-1, and 0-100 is needed.

This will work:

```
>>> newR = np.percentile(S, (100*u).tolist())
```

which works fine but might need its type adjusted if you want a numpy array back

```
>>> type(newR)
<type 'list'>

>>> newR = np.array(newR)
```

Now we have a numpy array.  Let's check the mean of the new random values.

```
>>> newR.mean()
0.25549728059744525 # close enough
```

Comment: could you elaborate further on how I generate a distribution similar to my data. I understand that random.random(4000) will generate 4000 random values within the range 0,1. But then how does numpy.percentile() make the randoms similar to my data distribution? How to do that?

Comment: I edited to address this.  For the math, see the wikipedia article for inverse transform sampling.

Comment: When I use pandas.series.quantile() it gives me only one value. I am not understanding this. Can you if possible elaborate? I now have a list of arrays with 4000 random numbers generated using numpy.random.normal with mean,stddev as per the data. Now how should I use this list/array of 4000 random numbers in series.quantile?

Comment: Thank you very much for your clean reply. I have tried what you told, but I cannot show you the histogram plot that I got here in the comments. Anyways, I had more values within 0- 0.10 which is the other way my real distribution is. What I then tried is changing the pow(S,3) to pow(S,0.5) which gave me the first half of a normal distribution. What I don't know is the DISTRIBUTION of my rel data, i.e what sort of distribution it follows so that I can replicate that to be my S!

Comment: You don't need to raise your sample to a power. That was just to create an example.  See the new edit.

Answer (score 6):

When using [`numpy.random.normal`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html) you can pass keyword arguments to set the mean and standard deviation of your returned array. These keyword arguments are `loc` (mean) and `scale` (std).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 4000
mean = 1.0
std = 0.5
x = []

while len(x) < N:
    y = np.random.normal(loc=mean, scale=std, size=1)[0]
    if 0.0 <= y <= 1.0:
        x.append(y)

plt.hist(x)
plt.show()
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: would like to know what the [0] in y = np.random.normal(loc=mean, scale=std, size=1)[0] stands for?

Comment: `y = np.random.normal(loc=mean, scale=std, size=1)` returns an array of size 1 so I am simply removing the first (0th) value of it to append to the list. Otherwise you'd append 4000 numpy-arrays with 1 element each.

Comment: OP's data doesn't remotely look like a segment of a normal distribution. Note that it's bimodal at around 0.5 and 1, and that your proposed normal solution returns too many values near 0. Given 4000 observations, any decent goodness of fit test will almost certainly reject the hypothesis that your data and the original data come from the same distribution. The suggestion to use bootstrapping or quantiles is a far better approach.

Comment: @pjs you're right they don't look identical. Of course I picked arbritrary values for `mean` and `std` which could effect the levels at lower values but there **is** a difference in shape. The OP however suggested that they themselves has been trying to use this method and had not been able to get it to work. As such I provided a method that did work based on the OPs original suggestion. If you feel that this deserves a downvote (as an answer that is not useful) then fair enough.

Comment: I think that OP trying to shoehorn it into a normal distribution is fundamentally misguided, and solutions that pursue that are inherently off-track and therefore not useful. **If** that were the way to go, your answer would be fine.

Answer (score 5):

If you can approximate the cumulative density function for the distribution (for example by taking cumsum of histogram) then sampling from that distribution becomes trivial.

```
Sample uniformly p in interval [0.0,1.0]
Lookup the value of x at which cdf(x) == p
```

I guess this is essentially what the answer involving Pandas is doing.

Answer (score 4):

You could use rejection sampling: You generate pairs (z,y) with 0<=y<=max(f(z)) until you get a pair with y<=f(z). The generated random number is z.

The advantage of the method is that it can be used for any distribution, but it may take many iterations until you get a valid pair (z,y).

Comment: I have found Adaptive Rejection Sampling to be a pretty good general-purpose method and can be implemented with a couple of dozen lines of code... http://www.medicine.mcgill.ca/epidemiology/joseph/courses/EPIB-675/adaptive.sampling.pdf. Although to be fair, Rejection sampling is only really necessary if you have access to the pdf but not the cdf. Since in this case, the cdf could be obtained by a cumsum on the histogram, rejection sampling seems overkill